# Ошибка установки NumPy с помощью pip. Используется PyCharm, а сним и .venv

Tags: python, numpy, pip

При установке библиотеки NumPy возникает ошибка:

```
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.26.3.tar.gz (15.7 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15.7/15.7 MB 7.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [40 lines of output]
      Collecting ninja>=1.8.2
        Downloading ninja-1.11.1.1.tar.gz (132 kB)
           ------------------------------------ 132.4/132.4 kB 649.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Building wheels for collected packages: ninja
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
     
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1
     
        [13 lines of output]
        C:\Users\ivash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-37t1ltze\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:308: UserWarning: git archive did not
 support describe output
          warnings.warn("git archive did not support describe output")
        C:\Users\ivash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-37t1ltze\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:327: UserWarning: unprocessed git arc
hival found (no export subst applied)
          warnings.warn("unprocessed git archival found (no export subst applied)")
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\ivash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-37t1ltze\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 645, in setup    
            cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
          File "C:\Users\ivash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-37t1ltze\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 148, in __init__
            self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
          File "C:\Users\ivash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-37t1ltze\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 105, in get_cmake_version 
            raise SKBuildError(msg) from err
     
        Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
        [end of output]
     
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for ninja
      Failed to build ninja
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
     
      [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.2
      [notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
      [end of output]

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Попробуйте переустановить https://python.org не забудьте поставить галочки на `Path` и `pip`

Comment: Переустановил, все галочки на месте, а ошибка осталась

Comment: попробуй даунгрейднуть версию Python. На том же python.org

Comment: Попробуйте тогда `pip install --upgrade cmake`

Comment: Похожая проблема: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77144310/17286989

Comment: У меня виндовс, а не линукс

Comment: Я заметил, вы попробуйте, пропуская пункт с apt

Comment: Все так же без результатов

Comment: Не знаю, у меня с тринадцатым питоном когда были такие проблемы, даунгрейд все решил. И не только у меня. Вы точно старую версию удалили?

Comment: К сожалению не так все просто

Comment: У меня рабочий код с многопоточностью перестал работать на python 3.12. Вернулся на 3.8 - всё работает. Почему у Вас "не всё так просто"? В чем проблема?